# java datasource with MySql

Tags: datasource

I installed MySql and i added in Eclipse mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar. After I have tested DriverManager class and it works. Now I would like to create a pooled connection for distributed transaction, but I need to know what I need to do (step by step, include eventually other imports (I am totally new in this)), oracle tutorial was not helping at all.

I am totally noob, it is not for work I am studing it. I have installed only MySql and Eclipse, I do not know about Weblogic or WebSphere. I used DriverManager connecting to localhost at the port 3306, and I wanted to know if I could do the same with the datasource without anything else.

Comment: if you are using servers like weblogic or websphere or in modern day servers, they are capable of creating connection pools . just you need to configure like max/min connections. once you configured this your server will create the connection pool, later through jndi  lookup you can get the datasouce . servers will manage the connections.

Comment: Let us know what application server you are using so that we can guide you with datasource configuration and lookup